# Dot separated urls

Tags: node.js, express

I am developing a *MEAN* stack application.

I can define routes like `website.com/seller/login`, `website.com/seller/dashboard`

But I want to define few routes like `seller.website.com/login` , `seller.website.com/dashboard`. 

How can I do that using express?

Comment: I don' think that you can create subdomains using express

Comment: okay, then how other websites are doing that?

Comment: I'd say they create a subdomain, then have express react on requests against that subdomain. A request to seller.website.com will just return that the address was not found if you haven't setup the subdomain's dns records.

Comment: You point the subdomain to your server? Do you even DNS man. Also do not use two types of url to get to the same place. Pick the former because you clearly have no idea how much of a PITA dns management is.

Answer (score -2):

From what I understand it must be the same. You must create a driectory "seller.website.com" under the "views" directory. The you must render the file from in it.

Then you must use this:
[Node.js virtula hosts](https://github.com/expressjs/vhost)

Comment: `seller.website.com` is not the directory, `seller.wesite.com` is the link.